# this error appeared after build - Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the problem in this code?

```
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await GetStorage.init();
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: ConstStyles.WhiteColor));
  runApp(
      MyApp(),);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // GlobalKey _scaffoldkey = GlobalKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      // key: _scaffoldkey,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      defaultTransition: Transition.downToUp,
      title: 'myapp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        backgroundColor: ConstStyles.WhiteColor,
        appBarTheme:AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: ConstStyles.DarkColor,
          centerTitle: true,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
      ),
      translations: Translation(),
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      locale:Locale('ar', 'EG'),

     initialRoute: Home.Id,
     getPages: Pages.routes,
    );
  }

}
```

this error appeared after run and also appeared in simulator mobile screen

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           107.6s
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51521/40h1M_ubZsc=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone 12 Pro Max...
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been initialized

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================

The following _CastError was thrown building Directionality(textDirection: rtl):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Directionality file:///Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.2.5/lib/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart:217:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 

#0      PageRedirect.page (package:get/get_navigation/src/routes/route_middleware.dart:198:50)

#1      GetMaterialApp.initialRoutesGenerate (package:get/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart:212:9)

#2      _WidgetsAppState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/app.dart:1533:51)

#3      NavigatorState.restoreState (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:3439:41)

#4      RestorationMixin._doRestore (package:flutter/src/widgets/restoration.dart:984:5)

...
====================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

add backslash
String id ='/home';
it's working with me